# Ghostscript - speed up PS files with 100's of pages for output to PDF files

Tags: multithreading, ghostscript

I'm an end-user not a programmer, but stuck with this project.

We have a large number of PS files we need to convert to PDF for viewing (proofing) prior to printing these PS files.  Each PS file contains 800 or fewer pages.  The PS files are normally 60-250 meg each.

The computer running the `Ghostscript` command is a `VM` install of `Win7 64 bit` running on `Server2012`.  The `VM` has 10 cores, 40 gigs of ram and a 4-disk RAID-0 using 15,000 rpm drives.  There is plenty of unused capacity if this helps.

The commands I have tried are:

```
gswin32c.exe -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE 
         -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite | 
         -sOutputFile="..\output.pdf"  -f "..\IN\input.ps"
```

and

```
gswin32c.exe -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH 
         -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNumRenderingThreads=3 |
         -sOutputFile="..\output.pdf"  -c "30000000 setvmthreshold" -f"..\IN\input.ps"
```

I did some testing comparing the rip speeds of these two commands, and the 2nd version with the Threads option is slower.  One of the test files has 90.5 megs of PS data, resulting in 716 pages in the PDF file.  The non-thread took 4.85 minutes vs. 5.93 minutes using the threaded version.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: -dNumRenderingThreads has absolutely no effect whatsoever on pdfwrite, because (TADA!) it doesn't render anything. The difference in performance will be due to the setvmthreshold. The conversion to PDF from PostScript is inherently single threaded, as you need to interpret the PostScript and that can't be parallelised (some files can be, but in general not). Oddly there is no -dSecretGoFasterSwitch the only real solution is as proposed by Will Hartung below, run multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

Run them simultaneously.

You have 10 cores, you should have at least 10 running all at the same time.

Find a set of options that performs better, individually, and simply run them all at the same time.

A trivial way to do this is create 10 batch files, each with a list of commands, that represent 10% of the files. Then fire off all of those batch files in separate command windows, and then head off to lunch to see what comes back.

Through scripting and forking and batching and other techniques, you could automate this more readily.

But I bet it would simply be faster for you to create 10 bat files in an editor, each with a list of mostly identical commands using cut and paste and search and replace.

If you do this a lot then perhaps find some help scripting that up.

If it's a one time thing, then just grind through it and create the files.

Then sit back and watch the fans spin on your VMs as the CPUs light up for an hour.

If you want to experiment, you could trying running 5, 6, 7, 8 at a time, checking clock time to see which nets fastest overall through put, and change the "10" to X appropriately.

But this is the simplest way to engage all the capacity of this machine.

Comment: thanks for the idea.  I will test this.  The volume of work comes in each month, so scripting it will be needed.  This past week we got 8,500 source pdf files, that when converted to PS (additional variable data added to the output PS files resulted in 187 PS files, with 45,000 individual pages.  <p>  Are there any changes to the gs command line options that will help speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

I was extracting "first pages" of ~10k PDFs and I used [ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) with [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to process everything in parallel. This is the "command" that I used:

```
find ./data/pdfs -name '*.pdf' | parallel \
  --verbose --progress \
  'gs -q -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -r500x500 -o {}.jpeg {}'
```

This was ran on OSX however you can get GNU Parallel on Windows via [CygWin](https://www.cygwin.com/).